# 2 ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

**Model:**

```
public class Order
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    public string UserName { get; set; }       

    public int Amount { get; set; }      

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string ManagerId { get; set; }     

}

 public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string NameSurname { get; set; }

    public bool IsCompany { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display 2 models in `Kendo Grid`. Sample code in View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<oko.Models.OrderDto>().Name("NewOrders").Columns(columns =>
{       
    columns.Bound(s => s.Username);
    columns.Bound(s => s.NameSurname);
    columns.Bound(s => s.Phone);
    columns.Bound(s => s.CreateDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");  
})
```

Field `UserName` they have the same. 
How to pass the fields `Phone` and `NameSurname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind to more than one class type, so the best way is to create a composite class ViewModel to hold the properties you need. Populate this in your controller, and pass this back to the model.

**Example view model**:

```
public class OrderDtoViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string NameSurname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    //etc...
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = _myRepository.GetYourData();

        var viewModel = new OrderDto()
        {
            UserName = data.UserName,
            NameSurname = data.NameSurname,
            Phone = data.Phone,
            CreateDate = data.CreateDate
        };

        return View(data)
    }
}
```

Then in your Kendo grid, use your composite view model (in above example called `OrderDtoViewModel`)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<oko.Models.OrderDtoViewModel>().Name("NewOrders").Columns(columns =>
{       
    columns.Bound(s => s.Username);
    columns.Bound(s => s.NameSurname);
    columns.Bound(s => s.Phone);
    columns.Bound(s => s.CreateDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");  
})
```